# How to explicitly convert type in Dynamic Linq Core?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-linq-core

I read the doc on Dynamic Linq Core [here](https://dynamic-linq.net/expression-language), where it says

> The expression language allows explicit conversions using the syntax type (*expr*), where type is a type name optionally followed by ? and *expr* is an expression. This syntax may be used to perform the following conversions:

I'm having a hard type following this instruction, so far I tried

```
.Select("new (Key.Date, Key.t, Sum(cashflow) as Profit, (double)Sum(cashflow) as TestConvertType)");
```

and

```
.Select("new (Key.Date, Key.t, Sum(cashflow) as Profit, Sum(cashflow).type(double) as TestConvertType)");
```

and I got

> "'.' or '(' or string literal expected"

I also tried:

```
.Select("new (Key.Date, Key.t, Sum(cashflow) as Profit, Convert.ToDouble(Sum(cashflow)) as TestConvertType)");
```

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

None worked. Can someone give me an example on how to explicitly convert type in Dynamic Linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it.. just use Type(expression)

```
.Select("new (Key.Date, Key.t, Sum(cashflow) as Profit, Double(Sum(cashflow)) as TestConvertType)");
```